# connecting to database using servlets

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets

I am trying to connect to database using java servlets. Somehow I am not able to get to display results on the web page. [Here](http://pastebin.com/6nk4dmGw) is my source code. Can anyone let me know if I am missing something?

If you want to downvote the question, supply a reason for doing so.

Comment: @Srikanth. No exception.

Comment: @ anyone down voting the question. give a reason.

Comment: I did not downvote, but your question is far too broad. You do not get any exceptions? Your query really returns data?

Comment: Read the tooltip of the downvote button for the major reason. Another reason is because you put the code on an external site. Put it in your question and elaborate in detail what exactly happens. Do some trivial debugging yourself. What lines are executed and what not? If for example `ResultSet#next()` never returns `true`, then it just means that your query is wrong or that the table is empty. This is then already not related to Java EE + Servlets. You would have exactly the same problem when doing it in a plain Java class with a `main()` method. Try to throw in some logical thinking powers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove the try catch of the SQLException

```
} catch(SQLException ex) {
```

and just throw the exception in the signature of the method to see if your code doesn't really throw an exception.

You're just writing to standard output in case of exception and you didn't tell us which server you're using. Your exception can be silently lost.

You should really use a logging framework instead, but for a quick check you can just add:

```
throws SQLException
```

to the method signature.

One more comment. I think you're learning about servlets so I will excuse your code, but in real life you don't want to use any SQL related method directly in a servlet.